# Javascript, Rails views, content_for and DRYness

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, layout, dry

In Rails, the common idiom for page-specific Javascript is:

(layout)

```
<head>
  <% yield :javascript %>
</head>
```

(view)

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $().whatever;
  </script>
<% end %>
```

I hate repeating the script tags. Is there any reason why the following is a bad idea?

(layout)

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <% yield :javascript %>
  </script>
</head>
```

(view)

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
    $().whatever;
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can put a `<script>` tag anywhere in the `<body>` and it will execute. Is there a particular reason you want to put it in the `<head>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that it's what is most specific to your use case.  Generally, when I use the <% yield :javascript %>, it's purpose is to add in page specific libraries, which would be a limitation to the approach you proposed.  If you want to support both, I have done the following:

(layout)

```
<head>
  <% yield :javascript_libraries %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <% yield :javascript %>
  </script>
</head>
```

(view)

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
    $().whatever;
<% end %>
<% content_for :javascript_library do %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'page-specific.js' %>
<% end %>
```

Of course most people put javascript libraries at the bottom for optimization of page loading, so then you could just move it in your layout.

Answer (score 2):

Idioms are great and all, but what matters most is you and your teams productivity and ability to maintain things, if you're OK with it I don't see any problem with it either. That said I've done this before and also seen it done in projects, although now I usually put it in a script file unless I absolutely have to have it in the specific page.

Comment: I agree. I would put it in a whatever.js file and: `<% content_for :javascript do -%><%= javascript_include_tag 'whatever' %><% end -%>`

Comment: But AIUI you can't render a .js view from .html, right? You still have to call it .html.erb? That really bugs me for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simplify your views, I highly recommend [HAML](http://haml-lang.com) (and it's sister SASS for CSS). There is a slight learning curve and you may not want to convert all your existing views at once, but I doubt that you'll ever want to go back to the ugly mess of ERB.

In HAML, this would look like:

```
= content_for :head do
  :javascript
    $().whatever;
```